# Bootstrap - Default CSS Box Shadow for Inputs with 'form-control' Class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, shadow

Does anyone know what the box shadow is that is applied to the Boostrap form-control inputs? I am looking to replicate the same blue glow that appears when you hover over an input that uses Bootstrap's form-control class. Would anyone be so kind as to share the CSS code?

I have looked through the Github for Boostrap but could not find it anywhere.

Thanks,

Comment: It's right there in the bootstrap.css just look it up

Comment: Or if you looked in dev tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
border-color: #66afe9;
outline: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
```

If you want to see the implementation of other components just inspect it - http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5.3.1:

```
.form-control:focus {
  color: var(--bs-body-color);
  background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);
  border-color: #86b7fe;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
}
```